# Fetching data from MySQL using phpMyAdmin for xcode

Tags: php, mysql

I have very minimal experience in PHP/MySQL.

I am attempting to fetch data from MySQL via phpMyAdmin and return it to xcode in a format it can understand.

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Table1'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Table1";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}


// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Now, while I do understand what's going on here to an extent, it only fetches data from one table.  If I wanted to fetch data from multiple tables in the database, how could I edit the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you are trying to achieve, you can join tables in a MySQL query, like:

```
SELECT o.*, c.companyName FROM orders o INNER JOIN customers c on o.customerId = c.id
```

This would return all of the order information and the customers company name from a related table.

If you want to return multiple different tables you may need to create multiple endpoints. maybe a customers.php, orders.php for example.

Personally myself, when creating a backend for a mobile project I will usually create a RESTful API using Symfony2, But this would take some time to learn.

This [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/basic-mysql-tutorial.aspx) may help with understanding MySQL

Comment: I have multiple tables.  Although, there is one main table that has a relation with the rest of the tables using foreign keys.  In this case, it would be 'Table1' in the above code.  All relationships are one-to-many.

Comment: The code above and the link provided will allow you to create the joins that you need to get the data, you'll likely need multiple different scripts to get different results